# What language cPanel/WHM panel server is done?

Tags: linux, perl, cpanel, whm

I am planning to make an application like cPanel/WHM in perl since i never worked out my own server in perl, and i was thinking of a few points that i wanted some advices/help:

- cpanel and whm work on ports 2082/3 and 2086/7 to server their panel i was wondering in what language is their server done or if there is a nice module for perl to hold a webserver like that ?
- from what i know cpanel/whm run as root what should i keep in mind while making my own server to handle my panel while it runs as root ?
- if you know of any open source USING
  PERL that is on this route i would
  like to take a look at it.

If you have any other advices related please feel free to drop your comment.

Best regards;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/), source code here: http://github.com/webmin/. It's an open-source alternative to cPanel, Plesk, etc. All of the modules appear to be written in perl. You can choose to extend it, or simply peruse the code to learn. Your choice.

Comment: thanks i will check that up, do you know which language is used for cpanel/whm server? i know they use a mix of lanaguages and one of is perl but dont know if perl is also used for the server.

Comment: According to the developer documentation it appears to be written in Perl. See http://www.cpanel.net/developer/documentation.html for more information.

Comment: Well it has some stuff in perl but not necessary the webserver from the docs you can't be sure it is in perl also i belive it is either compiled or something which makes me think perhaps `c` but thanks.

Comment: cPanel is a heavy Perl user. They sponsored this year's YAPC::EU for a reason. (Thank you, cPanel!)

Comment: Also, cPanel sponsored perlcc development. So if you see executable, it is written in Perl too.

Comment: @Alexandr Ciornii mmm i was under the impression that perlcc was no longer being supported or produced since the most recent comments regarding it on perlmonks.org was about it being dropped or so, but thanks i will take a look at it.

Comment: @Prix: perlcc was dropped from Perl core and abandoned. And later due to the efforts of Reini Urban and sponsorship of cPanel was revived on CPAN. I'm not sure if perlcc is usable generally - cPanel is oriented toward perlcc for older Perl version.

Comment: @Alexandr Ciornii is correct, cPanel is written in Perl, with the compiled executables compiled from Perl.  cPanel has a full-time perlcc developer contributing to the project.   Source: Former cPanel Employee

Answer (score 2):

For your own server I'd look at the [Plack/PSGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Plack/lib/Plack.pm) stack. Maybe with some [Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Runtime/lib/Catalyst.pm) to aid you.

Comment: Thanks, Catalyst is something already in the list ;) i will take a look at Plack.

Answer (score -1):

cPanel and WHM are both written in Perl and then compiled to native code.